# How to Disable Back Button when logout with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, logout

I am working on an application, and I want to disable the button back but just in one view (login view). When I click on logout, I am redirected to the first view which is login view, and here I want to disable the back button.
I have tried some solutions provided in this site, but they block the back button in all views.

This is my logout controller, and I have also a login controller for login view.

```js
app.controller('LogoutCtrl', function($scope, $location, $state, $http, $window, $rootScope, $cookieStore, $cookies) {

  $scope.logout = function() {
    var cookies = $cookies.getAll();
    angular.forEach(cookies, function(v, k) {
      $cookies.remove(k);
    });
  };
});
```

In my logout controller, I tried to delete all cookies because I am working with cookies, but I still have this problem of back button, and it allows the user to go to other view just with back button and without login.

How can I do this, please?

Comment: Are you referring to the browser's back button?

Comment: how do you handle your pages, you need to check if redirect to any part if isnt logged always redirect to login. no need to block backbutton

Comment: i think the problem is how you handled your sessions and states.

Comment: Can you give me an idea please! and how can I manage this!

Comment: did  you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your config/route file and change as you want

This will check every time at your route change

For example:-

```
angular
    .module('MyApp')
    .run(function($state, $scope,$cookies) {
       $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
         if(!$cookies.get('user')){
            $state.go('login');
         }
       })
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, I try it but I still have the same problem!

Comment: what  you are using ui-route or ng-route??